# How do I show that a single vector is a basis of this subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've been asked to show that the dimension of a certain subspace (intersection of 2 subspaces) is actually 1. My understanding is that the dimension is the number of vectors in the basis of a subspace. Given that $ X = \langle v \rangle$ and $v$ is given explicitly, I don't know what more to do to answer the question. How do I show something that seems to require little more than observation?

Or perhaps, I simply do not understand.

--

Let me show you the question:

I discovered that given two subspaces $U_1, U_2$ the following was true:

$$ U_1 \cap U_2 = \langle (1, 2, 0, 3) \rangle$$ (a column vector)

And the follow up question says show that $ \dim (U_1 \cap U_2) = 1$ and $ \dim (U_2) = 2$ where $U_2 = \langle (1, 2, 0, 3), (1, 0, 1, 1) \rangle$ (also column vectors). Now to me its pretty obvious that  $ \dim (U_1 \cap U_2) = 1$ and $ \dim (U_2) = 2$  are true just by looking at the findings.

Or should I first go about showing that these sets are indeed the basis of their respective subspaces and then state that these are one-/two- element sets and consequently the statements about the dimensions are true or...?

Comment: Could you ask the question more specifically? What vector in what space?

Comment: If you know that $X$ is the span of $\{v\}$, then yes, there’s nothing more to say. However, ‘dimension of a vector’ and ‘intersection of 2 vectors’ don’t really make sense, so perhaps you should say exactly how $X$ was defined.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hi, I went ahead and added more info for you.

Comment: @IanColey I edited the question and added more information

Comment: The only situation when there is a vector that is the only basis of a subspace is if your vector spaces are over the finite field of two elements, and your subspace has dimension 1. I think it is safe to assume this is not what you have here, so you seem to be misunderstanding something.

Comment: There's no such thing as the dimension of a vector.  There is such a thing as the dimension of a vector space.

Comment: I agree that if you’ve shown that $U_1\cap U_2=\langle(1,2,0,3)\rangle$, then it’s obvious that $\dim(U_1\cap U_2)=1$. In this case it’s also pretty obvious that $\dim U_2=2$, though technically you do have to show that those two vectors are linearly independent. It’s trivial, but some it’s technically necessary.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Oh, quite right. Thank you!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh, I see. I thought just as much, but often have trouble following my favorite professor's rule ("sometimes it *is* as easy as it looks"). Thanks for the information

Comment: To show that $\dim ⟨(1,2,0,3)⟩ = 1$, maybe you should remark that $(1,2,0,3)$ is not zero.  And similarly to show that $\dim ⟨(1,2,0,3),(1,0,1,1)⟩ = 2$ you should remark that these two vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: @Siyanda: You’re welcome. (‘Sometimes it really *is* that simple’ is one of my favorite observations, too.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’ve shown that $U_1\cap U_2=\langle(1,2,0,3)\rangle$, then it is obvious that $\operatorname{dim}(U_1\cap U_2)=1$; the only additional comment that you might want to make is that $(1,2,0,3)$ isn’t the zero vector, since if it were, the dimension of the subspace would be $0$. Here it’s also pretty obvious that $\operatorname{dim}U_2=2$, though technically you do have to show that those two vectors really are linearly independent. With just two vectors this is especially easy: a set of two vectors is linearly independent if and only if neither vector is a scalar multiple of the other. (If you’ve not seen this fact before, you should try to prove it; it’s not at all hard to do.)

A comment on the terminology in your original question: *the dimension of a certain vector* doesn’t make sense. Vector spaces have dimensions; individual vectors don’t.